# Connecting Redux to my React APP: Actions may not have an undefined "type" property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, flowtype

I'm new to Redux and i'm having a lot problems trying to connect Redux to my React App, whenever i type something on my input box i get this error:

> Uncaught Error: Actions may not have an undefined "type" property. Have you misspelled a constant?
>       at dispatch (eval at ./node_modules/redux/es/createStore.js (bundle.js:4248), :164:13)
>       at handleSearchTermChange (eval at ./js/Landing.jsx (bundle.js:757), :78:7)
>       at Object.executeOnChange (eval at ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/LinkedValueUtils.js (bundle.js:2779), :132:34)
>       at ReactDOMComponent._handleChange (eval at ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMInput.js (bundle.js:2899), :239:38)
>       at Object.ReactErrorUtils.invokeGuardedCallback (eval at ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactErrorUtils.js (bundle.js:3019), :69:16)
>       at executeDispatch (eval at ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/EventPluginUtils.js (bundle.js:2739), :85:21)
>       at Object.executeDispatchesInOrder (eval at ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/EventPluginUtils.js (bundle.js:2739), :108:5)
>       at executeDispatchesAndRelease (eval at ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/EventPluginHub.js (bundle.js:2723), :45:22)
>       at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (eval at ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/EventPluginHub.js (bundle.js:2723), :56:10)
>       at Array.forEach ()

This is my Landing.jsx:

```
// @flow

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import type { RouterHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { setSearchTerm } from './actionCreators';

class Landing extends Component {
  props: {
    searchTerm: string,
    handleSearchTermChange: Function,
    history: RouterHistory
  };
  goToSearch = (event: SyntheticEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.history.push('/search');
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="landing">
        <h1>svideo</h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.goToSearch}>
          <input
            onChange={this.props.handleSearchTermChange}
            value={this.props.searchTerm}
            type="text"
            placeholder="Search"
          />
        </form>
        <Link to="/search">or Browse All</Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ searchTerm: state.searchTerm });
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Function) => ({
  handleSearchTermChange(event) {
    dispatch(setSearchTerm(event.target.value));
  }
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Landing);
```

This is my store.js

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import reducers from './reducers';

const store = createStore(reducers);

export default store;
```

This is my action.js file:

```
/* This file will be a bunch of constants*/
export const SET_SEARCH_TERM = 'SET_SEARCH_TERM';
```

My actionCreators.js

```
import { SEARCH_SEARCH_TERM } from './actions';

/* Takes in a "searchterm" and it returns type and payload */

export function setSearchTerm(searchTerm: string) {
  return { type: SEARCH_SEARCH_TERM, payload: searchTerm };
}
```

And the reducer.js:

```
import { SET_SEARCH_TERM } from './actions';

const DEFAULT_STATE = {
  searchTerm: ''
};

const setSearchTerm = (state, action) => Object.assign({}, state, { searchTerm: action.payload });

const rootReducer = (state = DEFAULT_STATE, action: Action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_SEARCH_TERM:
      return setSearchTerm(state, action);
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export default rootReducer;
```

Really hope somebody can shed me a light here because I'm pretty new to the whole React, Redux, Flow and Type world.

Comment: Did you try changing in your reducer import statement to match the exact function you are exporting in your action creator?

Comment: What does your `actions.js` file look like?  It's likely you have an import/export mismatch with that file, so that `import {SET_SEARCH_TERM}` is ending up undefined.

Comment: Can you develop on that @joseatchang ? I don't think I understand what you mean. If I import setSearchTerm in reducers.js I have a flow error telling me that the function is already defined (which is true).

Comment: Thanks, @markerikson, I forgot to include that file on the post. I have updated it.

Comment: OOOOK, @markerikson, yes that was it, I have a typo on my actions.js and was importing something that was undefined. Solved, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the problem was that basically, I was trying to import a function that didn't exist because of a typo:

This is the declaration on my action.js file:

```
/* This file will be a bunch of constants*/
export const SET_SEARCH_TERM = 'SET_SEARCH_TERM';
```

and i was trying to import the const like this:

```
import { SEARCH_SEARCH_TERM } from './actions';

export function setSearchTerm(searchTerm: string) {
 return { type: SEARCH_SEARCH_TERM, payload: searchTerm };
}
```

SEARCH_SEARCH_TERM is undefined, I changed it to SET_SEARCH_TERM and now it's working. Kudos to @markerikson for his comment on the original post.